# Simplest method to call a function from keypress in python(3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keypress

I have a python application in which a function runs in a recursive loop and prints updated info to the terminal with each cycle around the loop, all is good until I try to stop this recursion.

It does not stop until the terminal window is closed or the application is killed (control-c is pressed) however I am not satisfied with that method.

I have a function which will stop the loop and exit the program it just never has a chance to get called in the loop, so I wish to assign it to a key so that when it is pressed it will be called.

What is the simplest method to assign one function to one or many keys?

Comment: what do you mean by "a recursive loop"?

Comment: as in a function which calls itself after it is called

Comment: you're recursing infinitely until someone tells it it stop?

Comment: yes, and that is how I want it to be setup to run until the user wants it to be stopped, if I was working with a gui it would be no big deal I could just create a "stop" button and just assign the function which stops my loop on that button's command however I cannot do that in this case

Comment: if you're just recursing over and over, eventually you're gonna hit the max recursion depth, so regardless of the solution here you'll want to switch it to a `while True` loop.  Would you be satisfied with having you exit function called when the user presses ctrl+c?

Comment: Instead of just extitng on Ctrl+C, defining the exit behavior.  Or are you trying to avoid Ctrl+C because you have something against the key combination itself?

Comment: That is true and not a bad method for the loop, however ctrl+c is how I have been stopping the program already. I am not complaining in fact I appreciate the insight but it does not answer the question asked.

Comment: I am more so looking for a single key press to terminate the program, it could be a specific key or just any key being pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept the `ctrl+c` signal and call your own function at that time rather than
exiting.

```
import signal
import sys

def exit_func(signal, frame):
    '''Exit function to be called when the user presses ctrl+c.
    Replace this with whatever you want to do to break out of the loop.
    '''
    print("Exiting")
    sys.exit(0) # remove this if you do not want to exit here

# register your exit function to handle the ctrl+c signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_func)

#loop forever
while True:
    ...
```

You should replace `sys.exit(0)` with something more useful to you.  You could raise an exception and that `except` on it outside the loop body (or just `finally`) to perform your cleanup actions.

Comment: I believe that is what I am looking for actually, mainly I wish for my function to handle the exit vs the default handling of sigint,                          I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

```
import keyboard
import sys
from time import sleep

def kb():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            print("A key was pressed")
            sys.exit(0)
        



def main():

    kb()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import keyboard

def mywait():
    keyboard.read_key()

def my_function():
    print("hello")

def my_exit():
    quit()

keyboard.add_hotkey('h', my_function)
keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', my_exit)

while True:
    mywait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code

```
import keyboard
import sys

def kb():
    while True:
        #your code here
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"): #replace with your key
            print("Key interrupt detected")
            #cleanup here
            sys.exit()
        #or here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    kb()
```

This program checks if you have pressed the key "A" every cycle. If you have, it exits.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).